# How can I plot a colormap with discrete intervals in xarray and avoid Error Passing a Normalize instance simultaneously with vmin/vmax not supported

Tags: python, python-xarray, colorbar, boundary, norm

I want to get a plot a colormap with discrete intervals, each interval associated to a color. My dataset is in xarray and works well. I tried the code below but I get the following error. I tried with norm.vmax=100 and without.  Any help is welcome.

> ValueError: Passing a Normalize instance simultaneously with vmin/vmax is not supported.  Please pass vmin/vmax directly to the norm when creating it.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(10, 7))
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['blue', 'yellow', 'red'])
bounds = np.array([0, 1, 5,100]) norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
norm.vmax=100 norm.vmin=0
ds_p.plot(cmap=cmap, norm=norma, cbar_kwargs={'pad' :0.1, 'shrink': 0.5, 'label':  '[% of year]'}) plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try passing the `levels` argument to your plot method.

See [here](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v0.7.0/plotting.html#discrete-colormaps) for details.